# Error: array indices cannot be string

Tags: python-2.7

I am using Python to extract specific string from response in JSON.

```
def extract_description(texts):
"""Returns all the text in text annotations as a single string"""
document = ''
for text in texts:
    try:
        document += text['description']
    except KeyError as e:
        print('KeyError: %s\n%s' % (e, text))
return document
```

But i get the error: `Error: array indices cannot be string`. I tried using:

```
for text in texts:
     try:
         if text == 'description':
             document += text
     except KeyError as e:
         print('KeyError: %s\n%s' % (e, text))
return document
```

But the result is `''`, document is null. Is there another and better way to do this?

texts is:

```
   {u'textAnnotations': [{u'locale': u'eo', u'description': 
    u"...discovered
    text....", u'boundingPoly': {u'vertices': [{u'y': 32, u'x': 21},    
    {u'y': 32,
    u'x': 954}, {u'y': 685, u'x': 954}, {u'y': 685, u'x': 
    21}]}}]}]}**strong text**
```

This code is by Google Cloud API. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/tree/master/python/text.

Comment: What is in `texts`?

Comment: @ScottHunter I edited my question, have a look

Comment: What you posted for `texts` isn't a valid Python expression.  But your original Python code wasn't valid, either (indentation matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my best guess at what `texts` actually contains (what was posted isn't a valid Python expression), it looks like you need something like this:

```
for text in texts:
    document += texts[text][0]['description']
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try it out and if it works ill upvote it:)